# Current limiter

Tags: current

[image]

I would like to use a modified version of this circuit  with the Vin gauge being 13 g  and the Vout (load) being 14g  in an AC circuit. Aside from changing the op amp,and R6 how can i make this suitable for an AC circuit?[image]

Comment: I'm baffled? What does "Vin gauge being 13 g" actually mean in real words? Anyone?

Comment: The way the LED is controlled is very strange and inefficient. The normal way of doing it is changing the resistance of a transistor, connected in series.

In this circuit the transistor is connected in parallel to the LED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use this type of circuit to limit a 20A AC line current unless it can dissipate hundreds of watts and withstand thousands of volts. (3kV)

In order to define a solution, you have a duty to define the problem with measurements and expected over-current limits and time duration.

Start surge current limiting is sometimes done with NTC poly-resitors.

It is always easier to limit current by regulating the load.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail. My goal is to limit  the amount of current coming from the 13 gauge wire  go into a 14 gauge wire.

Comment: I understood that already. but that is not something one normally does.  You only choose a fuse, breaker or load to suit the wire.  But we'll never know with your lack of details on the application , load, concerns etc. It seems illogical.

Comment: By the way, a 14 AWG wire can take surges greater and RMS rating. and AWG13 has only 30% more resistance thus temp rise accordingly.  (approx) 3 wire gauges smaller = 50% lower Ohms/m